# What are the differences between a program and an application?

Tags: computer-science, terminology

What are the differences between a program and an application?

I am trying to understand this to form a concept in ontology. Can anyone explain?

Comment: Program is the most general term. Programs subdivides into Application Programs (Applications) and Utility programs (Utilities). Applications are intended to solve the tasks related to the main activity of the user. Photoshop is an application for graphic designers, Vim is an application for developers. Utilities are intended to solve system-specific tasks, e.g. to fix the problems in the Windows registry or undelete the files. MiniTool Power Data Recovery is an utility.

Comment: From the system administrator's point of view the utilities are applications (because the main activity of system administrator is to maintain the system).

Answer (score 63):

My understanding is this:

- A **[computer program](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_program)** is a set of instructions that can be executed on a computer.
- An **[application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_software)** is software that directly helps a user perform tasks.
- The two intersect, but are not synonymous. A program with a user-interface is an application, but many programs are not applications.

Comment: I like this answer because it approaches from the "technical" side -- but can't up-vote for awhile :( However, it's important to acknowledge that to most end-users a "program" and an "application" are the same thing. I generally use the same term ("this program sucks" or "you need to install the application on the server") unless there is a reason to separate the terms.

Comment: From a developer's perspective I don't see a difference between the two. From the user's perspective, though, I can see the difference.

Comment: I see "application" as the usage of one or more computer programs to meet certain user needs. "An application of various components allowing the user to paint amusing pictures."

Comment: Both can directly help a user to perform tasks.

Comment: I also may suggest that: application often is a set of programs

Answer (score 17):

When I studied IT in college my prof. made it simple for me:

"A computer "program" and an "application" (a.k.a. 'app') are one-in-the-same.
The only difference is a technical one. While both are the same, an 'application' is a computer program launched and dependent upon an operating system to execute."

Got it right on the exam.

So when you click on a word processor, for example, it is an application, as is that hidden file that runs the printer spooler launched only by the OS. The two programs depend on the OS, whereby the OS itself or your internal BIOS programming are not 'apps' in the technical sense as they communicate directly with the computer hardware itself.

Unless the definition has changed in the past few years, commercial entities like Microsoft and Apple are not using the terms properly, preferring sexy marketing by making the term 'apps' seem like something popular market and 'new', because a "computer program" sounds too 'nerdy'. :(

Comment: I like the definition of your teacher. I belive it's the corret one.

Comment: all userland programs are "dependent on an operating system to execute"

Comment: No description about programm

Answer (score 3):

A "program" can be as simple as a "set of instructions" to implement a logic.

It can be part of an "application", "component", "service" or another "program".

Application is a possibly a collection of coordinating program instances to solve a user's purpose.

Answer (score 2):

i guess you mean System Programs and Application programs

System Programs makes the hardware run , Applications are for specific tasks

an Example for System Programs are Device Drivers

as for the Applications you can say web browsers , word porcessros etc

Answer (score 2):

Without more information about the question, the terms 'program' and 'application' are nearly synonymous.

As Saif has indicated, 'application' tends to be used more for non-system related programs. That being said, I don't think it's wrong to describe the operating system as an special application that provides an environment in which to run other applications.

Comment: thanks all, by that i can use both terms interchangeably

Comment: @waterlilies There are many terms which can be used interchangeably in some context (e.g. colloquially) -- but not in other contexts (e.g. when formalized jargon is required). The former case is generally imprecise where the latter may require a high degree of accuracy as the terms may have subtle (expected) implications.

Answer (score 1):

I use the term program to include applications (apps), utilities and even operating systems like windows, linux and mac OS. We kinda need an overall term for all the different terms available. It might be wrong but works for me. :)